# Ruby: Can I get an instance by its ID?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, if I have the ID of an object instance as a string, such as
`"#<Meeting:0x4531860>"`, can I get the instance its self by this ID?

```
# what I want
meeting = SOME_MAGIC_HERE "#<Meeting:0x4531860>"
# and then I can handle the meeting itself
meeting.name # => 'BLABLABLA'
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate unless you consider the conversion from the ID displayed in inspection to the object id is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
meeting = ObjectSpace._id2ref(0x4531860 >> 1)
```

Comment: thats super awesome. Just one thing '0x4531860' looks like the memory address of the object? if yes wont it become invalid after some time(once that memory space is used)?

Comment: @sahildhankhar It is not memory address. And yes, if the object is garbage collected, then it will be invalid. In that case, there is no way to refer to that object as it would be gone.